# Using VB.NET for Azure authentication (connect-azaccount)

Tags: vb.net, azure

Disclaimer: New to Azure so please be gente :)

I can connect to our azure tenant using powershell using Connect-AzAccount

```
Connect-AzAccount -Environment AzureCloud -Tenant $TenantDomain -CertificateThumbprint $CertificateThumbprint -ApplicationId $AppId
```

Now, I want to do the same in a VB.NET console application. Assuming I have all the same parameters I have used in the powershell script, how do I go about it? All I can figure out so far is I need to use the Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll for implementing this although I can't find any relevant articles

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Eventually, we want to be able to get users and group memberships from AAD

Comment: Azure Powershell is a front-end for Azure REST API calls, if you want to do the same from a console app, you need to get an access token and use it against the appropriate Azure AD REST API endpoints. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966529/is-it-possible-to-use-azuread-authentication-with-a-console-application for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that link and try it out